# LATEX - list of items using enumerate for typesetting a dichotomous key (Bestimmungsschluessel)

Tags: macros, lists, enumerate, algorithms

Today I am looking for a way to typeset a dichotomous key (German: Bestimmungsschluessel, biol.) with LATEX using the

```
\begin{enumerate}    
\item ...   
\end{enumerate}
```

environment.

Such a key is used for plants or animals and is used like this:
Choose one of two options

```
>1   description one .... go to #2   
>1*  description alternative one ... go to #4   
>2   description two ... go to    
>2*  description alt. two   
>...   
>...
```

It should look like this, (real example on German): http://www.sn.schule.de/~biologie/lernen/bestimmung/schlussel.html

So I need a list for automatically numbering every second item with the same number and a star-like symbol within the enumerate environment.
Creating a fixed list might not do, because there is a high possibility of adding further items.

Additionally, it might be very helpful to set a

```
\ref
```

at the end of each line to get to the next number.    Is there a way to NOT label each item and using ref manually? Just thinking about a possible description of more than a 1000 plants or 600 and 600* items.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
% \maketitle
% \clearpage

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{item1} \lipsum[1] \dotfill \ref{item2} % this would be #1 description one  ... hinting to #2
\item              \lipsum[2] \dotfill \ref{item3} % this would be #1* description alternative one ... hinting to #3
\item\label{item2} \lipsum[3] \dotfill  \ref{item4} % this would be #2 description two ... hinting to #4
\item              \lipsum[4] \dotfill  % \ref{item5} % this would be #2 description two ... hinting to #5
\item\label{item3} \lipsum[5] \dotfill  % \ref{item10} 
\item              \lipsum[6] \dotfill
\item\label{item4} \lipsum[7] \dotfill  
\item              \lipsum[8] \dotfill
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Things I tried, who did not work for me (but feel free to try again!):

```
\setlist[]{} 
\newcounter{}
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance!!

Comment: doing it the very hard way:  use `\begin{description} \item[1~~~]\label{itema1} .... \item[1*~~] .... \end{description}` is possible, but no way for more than 10 times 2 entries. Furthermore no automatically numbering or references...

Comment: Does your list always have a starred number for every unstarred one? So, 600 plants will require a list containing 1200 items?

Comment: @Werner: yes, indeed. 600 was just an example, but I already got really tired after 10*2 entries. So I was looking for a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox}

\setlist[1]{labelindent=\parindent}

\newlist{Bestimmungsschluessel}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Bestimmungsschluessel]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*, labelsep=10pt, format=\bfseries}

\newcounter{schlussel}
\setcounter{schlussel}{0}

\newcommand\iitem{%
  \refstepcounter{schlussel}%
  \ifnumodd{\value{schlussel}}{\iitemnostar}{\iitemstar}%
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\iitemstar{%
  \item[\@itemlabel\rlap{*}]}

\newcommand\iitemnostar{\item}

\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\begin{Bestimmungsschluessel}
\iitem One  \label{one}
\iitem One*
\iitem Two  \label{two}
\iitem Two*
\iitem Three.  See \ref{two}.
\iitem Three*. See \ref{one}.
\end{Bestimmungsschluessel}

\end{document}
```

If you want to have things like multiple optional arguments and conditional behaviour, it is best to use a delimited argument, so `\iitem final description of plant or animal` is not a good way to do it.

But with `xparse`, you can easily construct a delimited argument:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\iitem}{omd()o}{%
% usage: \iitem[<label>]{<mandatory text>}(<Latin name>)[<label>]
  \refstepcounter{schlussel}%
  \ifnumodd{\value{schlussel}}{\iitemnostar}{\iitemstar}%
  \space
  \IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}}%
  #2%
  \dotfill
  \IfValueTF{#3}{\textsc{#3}\space}{\relax}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{\bsrefstring \space \ref{#4}}%
}
```

Basically, everything else stays the same, though you will also need to revise how you use `\iitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem, etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setlist[1]{labelindent=\parindent}

% Set up new list
\newlist{Bestimmungsschluessel}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Bestimmungsschluessel]{leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*, labelsep=10pt, format=\bfseries}

\newcounter{schlussel}
\setcounter{schlussel}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\iitem}{omd()o}{%
% usage: \iitem[<label>]{<mandatory text>}(<Latin name>)[<label>]
  \refstepcounter{schlussel}%
  \ifnumodd{\value{schlussel}}{\iitemnostar}{\iitemstar}%
  \space
  \IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}}%
  #2%
  \dotfill
  \IfValueTF{#3}{\textsc{#3}\space}{\relax}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{\bsrefstring \space \ref{#4}}%
}

% An optional text string for the cross-references
\newcommand*{\bsrefstring}{Please see \S.\@}



\makeatletter

\newcommand{\iitemstar}{\item[\@itemlabel\rlap{*}]}
\newcommand\iitemnostar{\item}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Bestimmungsschluessel}
% usage: \iitem[<label>]{<MANDATORY text>}(<Latin name>)[<ref>]
\iitem[labelone]{Text one}
\iitem{One*}(Plantus officinale (L.))
\iitem[labeltwo]{Text two, ref to labelone}[labelone]
\iitem{Two*, ref to labeltwo}[labeltwo]
\iitem[labelthree]{Text three, ref to labelone}[labelone]
\iitem{Text three*, ref to label three}(Other thing)[labelthree]
\end{Bestimmungsschluessel}

Please refer to labelone (\ref{labelone}), labeltwo (\ref{labeltwo}), and labeltree (\ref{labelthree}).

\end{document}
```

Once commands start getting this complex, however, a so-called 'key-value' approach starts making more and more sense.

Comment: This works like a dream! But, as an extra, how to include  a text-variable, `\dotfill`, `\label{}` or `\ref{}` as options of the new iitem? Would this be possible by a `\newenvironment`?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would want to use the command? `\label` and `\ref` seem fairly straightforward, but how would `\dotfill` be used?

Comment: Taking your command `\newcommand\iitem{%
  \refstepcounter{schlussel}%
  \ifnumodd{\value{schlussel}}{\iitemnostar}{\iitemstar}%
  \atextvariable \label{}  \dotfill \ref{}
}` (not working) and adding some parameters for a macro to include the needed commands by default.                 So to say, a wishfull thinking of `\iitem{auto. enumeration(given)}{text}{\label{}}{\dotfill(given)}{\ref{}}`.     `\dotfill` is just used for optics and getting `\ref{}` at the end of the line, optics comparable to `\tableofcontents'.

Comment: So a command with usage like: `\iitem[<label>]{<text>}[<ref>]` where `\label` and `\ref` are optional arguments, or are they mandatory arguments?  And if there's no `\ref`, then is there still a `\dotfill`?

Comment: Exactly, `\label` and `\ref` would be optional. And if there is no `\ref` used, then there is still a `\dotfill`, because the ultimate goal of such a key  would then be something like: `\begin{Bestimmungsschluessel}
\iitem final description of plant or animal. \dotfill \textsc{Plantus officinale (L.)}
\end{Bestimmungsschluessel}`

Comment: Wow, that's indeed complex. Though it should not be written here: thank you very much for your huge efforts!   Meanwhile, I used a dirty work-around for huge numbers of items by listing all <text>, etc. in calculator/excel - export as .csv - import in R - adding all necessary LATEX commands automatically via for-loop - export as .tex and import in latex.

Comment: Ah, well, that'll make it easier to write the data into a delimited macro!

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. What do you mean by delimited macro?

Comment: One that is 'delimited' by some means or another. The most common is braces `\mycmd{this is delimited}`. The delimited macros with several arguments are annoying to write if you use the command frequently: `\mycmd{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}`. But if you have mandatory and optional (and/or conditional) arguments, then they are the 'safest' way to design the macro ... rather than `\iitem[<optional arg.>] <mandatory text but not delimited> [<optional arg.>]`.